# cannot find DIOSConfig.h file in my XCode project

Tags: iphone, ios, drupal-services

We are working on making an iphone app for a drupal website. We want to use XML-RPC for communication.

We have added the DIOS sdk and AFNetwork library into a XCode project. According to two tutorials I viewed, the next step is to modify a file called DIOSConfig.h and give the url of the drupal services function in that file. But I cannot find that file.

Will I have to enter the url in a different file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify **Settings.h** file

Refer to this link https://github.com/workhabitinc/drupal-ios-sdk